# RegEx: remove double <br /> tags

Tags: php, regex

I have a dynamic string, that may contain h2 tags and in those h2 tags some br tags. I want to remove those br tags from the string.

```html
<h2>Headline 1</h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr.<h2>Headline 2 <br /><br /></h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr<h2>Headline 2<br /><br /></h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr<h2>Headline 2</h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr
```

To remove the br tags, I use this regex:

```
/<h2.*?>.+?(<br[\s+]?\/>).+?<\/h2>/
```

The problem is, that my first match is `<h2>Headline 1</h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr.<h2>Headline 2 <br /><br /></h2>`.
Yes, works as designed :-) But how can I make regex only capture the groups with a br in the h2 tags?

Comment: What language/tool are you using?

Comment: I'm using PHP 7.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be much easier to do it in more than 1 step:

1. Use regex to extract the `<h2>...</h2>` sequence
2. Use regex to remove the `<br />` tags from the `<h2>...</h2>` sequence
3. Write the new string
4. Copy everything else as-is

---

Alternatively, search for:

```
(<\s*h2[^<]*>[^<]*)<\s*br\s*\/\s*>
```

and replace with:

```
\1
```

Repeat until no more replacements are done.

Test [**here**](https://regex101.com/r/Pv1Uf4/1).

---

The other solution (smarter) is to use a proper HTML parser and do all the magic you want.

Comment: exactly! Thx u so much

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use a DOM parser.

But, if you really want to use regex, that is acceptable in this case, you can use preg_replace_callback:

```
$html = '<h2>Headline 1</h2>Lorem ipsum.<h2>Headline 2 <br /><br /></h2>dolor sit amet,<h2>Headline 2<br /><br /></h2>consetetur<br /> sadipscing elitr<h2>Headline 2</h2>Lorem<br /> ipsum';

# first, extract the string inside <h2>...</h>
$res = preg_replace_callback('~<h2>\K.*?(?=</h2>)~', 
            function($m) {
                # then remove the <br />
                return  preg_replace('~<br />~', '', $m[0]);
            },
            $html);

echo $res;
```

**Output:**

```
<h2>Headline 1</h2>Lorem ipsum.<h2>Headline 2 </h2>dolor sit amet,<h2>Headline 2</h2>consetetur<br /> sadipscing elitr<h2>Headline 2</h2>Lorem<br /> ipsum
```